# Announcement and time indications

Tags: discussion, feature-request, timezone

At the time of writing, the SO site shows the following announcement:

> We will be moving all Stack Exchange services to the backup data center at approximately 3:00 UTC (11 am EDT) causing a brief read-only period on the Q&A sites (details here)

Why does SO only mention American times and not even GMT? I have no idea about UTC and EDT by I know exactly where I am relative to GMT. Would it be possible to change this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Comment: How is UTC an "American" time?

Comment: @CodyGray it also says `11 am EDT` which would be American time.

Comment: It is weird that this kind of questions always get downvoted. What's wrong with asking to make things a little easier?

Comment: FWIW, its 15:00 UTC and 11am EDT. 3:00 UTC implies 3 in the morning.

Comment: @StevenV If... the 12 hour clock is being used with UTC that's a bit weird and aught to be corrected.

Comment: downvoted because murka.

Comment: It didn't get downvoted because people don't want to make things easier. It got downvoted because UTC isn't "American" time and UTC/GMT are essentially the same.

Answer (score 7):

Everything on Stack Exchange uses UTC for the date/time, this makes it much easier to use a single value instead of trying to keep track of local times for each user.  This was previously discussed on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2941/why-are-the-time-stamps-in-utc-instead-of-localized-for-the-client).

Instead of displaying a different time for everyone, [it was decided](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62853/stack-exchange-sites-need-a-universal-clock-that-is-visible) to put the UTC time in the top bar menu drop down:

[image]

If you look here, then you will know when this will impact you locally.

Comment: If I want to know what time UTC is in my country, I have to check or convert it. This is a bad answer.

Comment: @Mark But now you know that UTC is basically GMT and you already said that you know the offset for GMT I'm a bit confused about what your proposal is?

Comment: @Mark You look at the time in UTC through the achievements menu, and check the difference on your desktop. Use this difference to figure it out. Either that, or search google for "15:00 UTC to <your preferred timezone>" and it'll tell you the time of it. (Other search engines are available)

Answer (score 4):

On the sites everything is in UTC for simplicity, and we specify the EST/EDT time since most of the team is on the East coast of the United States.

We can't reasonably post the time things will be happening in every time zone. GMT is UTC +0 so your math is pretty simple.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) has the answer:

> The term Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) does not have a precise definition at the sub-second level, but it is often considered equivalent to UTC or UT1. Saying "GMT" often implies either UTC or UT1 when used within informal or casual contexts. In technical contexts, usage of "GMT" is avoided; the unambiguous terminology "UTC" or "UT1" is preferred.

While I'm not sure why Stack Exchange decided to use UTC everywhere, the ambiguity could be a factor.

Comment: Besides the lack of a precise definition (only UTC is tracked as an official time, based on the earth's rotation), GMT is ambiguous. It is variously used as a synonym for UTC as well as the local timezone for the UK/Ireland/Lisbon/et al.

Comment: @CodyGray Not by people in the UK it isn't. We move from GMT to BST (British Summer Time)

Comment: Right, that's exactly the point, @Martin. At least in my experience, there's a lot of confusion about whether GMT implies a switch to "GMT Daylight Time" (which doesn't really exist, but is effectively BST), or whether it means UTC. I mean, I don't know, I've never lived in Britain, so maybe you guys aren't confused. But plenty of other people I've dealt with are. :-)